# ASIFormDataRequest .NET WebService

Tags: iphone, web-services, cocoa-touch

I have a form in my iPhone application which contains three textFields and a post-button, of course.

I have built two WebMethods in a WebService, I have tried both from my local PC. They works perfectly. The methods are:

> 1. TestAddData - no parameters
> 2. AddObject(string name, string address, string phoneNumber)

I know wonder how to call this web services from my iPhone application. The current code:

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/Service.asmx"];
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [request startSynchronous];

        // Parameters:
 //[request setPostValue:@"value" forKey:@"parameterInMethod"];
 //[request setPostValue:@"value" forKey:@"parameterInMethod"];
```

**Edit:**
I figured out how to select which method to call. The code for that was:

```
[request setRequestMethod:@"TestAddData"];
```

But it returns **403 - Forbidden**. The Service.asmx-file is *read* and *write*.

Both my WebMethods is public. TestAddData is "public string", and AddObject is "public void".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI,Sorry my friend i didn't got your problem actually. But
    * 403.1 - Execute access forbidden.
    * 403.2 - Read access forbidden.
    * 403.3 - Write access forbidden.
    * 403.4 - SSL required.
    * 403.5 - SSL 128 required.
    * 403.6 - IP address rejected.
    * 403.7 - Client certificate required.
    * 403.8 - Site access denied.
    * 403.9 - Too many users.
    * 403.10 - Invalid configuration.
    * 403.11 - Password change.
    * 403.12 - Mapper denied access.
    * 403.13 - Client certificate revoked.
    * 403.14 - Directory listing denied.
    * 403.15 - Client Access Licenses exceeded.
    * 403.16 - Client certificate is untrusted or invalid.
    * 403.17 - Client certificate has expired or is not yet valid.
  it may work for you.Check which type of error occur.

Comment: ASIFormDataRequest only returns HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden